# Kafka Dotnet Builders best practices

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I am using dotnet to build a Kafka application and I found that [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Confluent.Kafka/1.9.0-RC7) NuGet package from Confluent.

The documentation is okay, but I was wondering the following: I have a controller, and I will receive multiple requests, where I will use a producer to insert data into a Kafka topic. But I'm not sure what to do with the `ProducerBuilder` class. Should I create a producer on each request, or just a producer per the lifetime of the app? What are the pros & cons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Producer instances should only be created once, per unique producer configuration. One instance can write to many topics. You need a builder to get the instance.

You should be able to inject a built Producer into your Service/Controller classes rather than needing to rebuild one on each request.

Comment: Okay, that's good to hear. Their examples always show something like `using (var prod = ProducerBuilder(...)` so I'm guessing that in this case, I need to keep an `IProducer` as a field, implement `IDisposable` and manually call `Dispose` on the producer.

Comment: You shouldn't close the producer after each request, either, only during your application teardown lifecycle